# If python set does not allow the mutable object then why it allow to add a list with single element

Tags: python

I read one [article](http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php):

*"Sets are implemented in a way, which doesn't allow mutable objects"*

When I execute :

```
 cities = set((["Python","Perl"], ["Paris", "Berlin", "London"]))
```

It throws *error*:

`TypeError: list objects are unhashable`

I searched for this error and understood that set does not allow the mutable objects hence it throws this error. But as you can see the element inside the set is a tuple which is immutable so set should allow it. checked with `type()`
But when I tried :

```
cities = set((["Python","Perl"]))
```

It worked even if the element inside the set is mutable list.
I am really confused here.
I am confused now. :-(

Comment: Try checking the type of the elements of the set.

Answer (score 1):

> it worked even if the element inside the set is mutable list

You are initializing the set with a single argument `(["Python","Perl"])`, which is the same as `["Python","Perl"]`, i.e. a list of strings.

The set unpacks this list, leaving it with two elements of type `str`:

```
>>> cities = set((["Python","Perl"]))
>>> for c in cities: print type(c), c
<type 'str'> Python
<type 'str'> Perl
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, hashable and immutable are not the same thing. The [python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) contains a definition of hashable:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() or **cmp**() method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they  all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is their id().

As you can see, any object that implements `__hash__`, `__eq__` and `__cmp__` can be added to a set. The wisdom of implementing these methods for highly mutable objects such as lists is questionable, but it can be done. Immutability is by no means a requirement.

Secondly a set can be initialized from a list, as long as each of elements is hashable. The line `cities = set((["Python","Perl"]))` constructs a set with `Python` and `Perl` as the elements. Note that the extra parentheses do not create a tuple. Adding an extra comma, `cities = set((["Python","Perl"],))` would give you the same error as before since now you will have a tuple. In this case, the tuple attempts to compute a hash, but its hash depends on the hashes of the lists, which do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tuple of tuples in your example you should try:

```
cities = set((("Python","Perl"), ("Paris", "Berlin", "London")))
print cities #Output set([('Paris', 'Berlin', 'London'), ('Python', 'Perl')])
type(cities) #Output <type 'set'>
```